# Как докер создает несколько сетей на машине?

Tags: docker

командой

> docker network ls

можно найти сети, которые создал докер. Не могу осознать, как вообще возможно создать несколько сетей на машине?

Comment: А то, как драйвер создает сеть, у Вас нет вопросов? Просто виртуальная сетевая карта

Answer (score 0):

так же, как это «делает» и, например, программа *ip* (понятно, что не она сама, а программа *linux*, но не будем усложнять).

например, создадим интерфейс типа `dummy` с именем `blabla`:

```
$ sudo ip l a blabla type dummy
```

и посмотрим на него:

```
$ ip l sh blabla
271: blabla: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:2d:31:42:96:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

есть такая буква в этом слове! ну, добавим к этому интерфейсу пару ip-адресов:

```
$ sudo ip a a 1.2.3.4/24 dev blabla
$ sudo ip a a 4.3.2.1/30 dev blabla
```

вот они:

```
$ ip a sh blabla
271: blabla: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:2d:31:42:96:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 scope global blabla
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 4.3.2.1/30 scope global blabla
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

налюбовавшись, удалим интерфейс:

```
$ sudo ip l d blabla
```

и проверим:

```
$ ip l sh blabla
Device "blabla" does not exist.
```

---

пояснения сокращений (можно указывать и полную форму):

- `ip l a` = `ip link add`
- `ip l sh` = `ip link show`
- `ip a a` = `ip address add`
- `ip a sh` = `ip address show`
- `ip l d` = `ip link delete`